# drush sql-sync structure tables in alias dont work

Tags: drush

It seems that the structure tables dont work on a sql sync from my live site to my dev. Using the following comman:

drush sql-sync @example.live @example.dev

The search_api_server is every time overritten, so it gets synced. So i think also my cache tables get synced. Whats wrong with my aliases?

```
/**
 * Dev/Local alias
 */
$aliases['dev'] = array(
  'root' => '/var/www/example_dev',
  'uri'  => 'example.dev',
  'path-aliases' => array(
    '%files' => 'sites/default/files',
  ),
  'source-command-specific' => array (
    'sql-sync' => array (
      'no-cache' => TRUE,
      'structure-tables-key' => 'common',
    ),
  ),
  // No need to modify the following settings
  'command-specific' => array (
    'sql-sync' => array (
      'sanitize' => TRUE,
      'no-ordered-dump' => TRUE,
      'structure-tables' => array(
       // You can add more tables which contain data to be ignored by the database dump
        'common' => array('cache', 'cache_filter', 'cache_menu', 'cache_page', 'history', 'sessions', 'watchdog','search_api_server'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

/**
 * Live alias
 */
$aliases['live'] = array(
  'remote-host' => '000.000.00.00',
  'remote-user' => 'username',
  'root' => '/var/www/html/example-live',
  'uri'  => 'example.net',
  'path-aliases' => array(
    '%files' => 'sites/default/files',
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three places you can reference aliases when using sql-sync:

drush @site sql-sync @prod @dev

@site - Where the sql-sync will execute. If this is a remote site, then the other two aliases must be defined in files that reside on the remote machine.  Options from 'command-specific' will be applied to the command.

@prod - The source for the sync.  Options from 'source-command-specific' will be applied to the command.

@dev - The target for the sync.  Options from 'target-command-specific' will be applied to the command.

The alias @site is not usually used with sql-sync; most people just run `drush sql-sync @prod @dev`.

Drush is going to look for *different* 'command-specific' records depending on the position of the alias appears on the commandline.

@site - The alias that appears before the command name will have options from the 'command-specific' -> 'sql-sync' record added to the evaluated options list.

@prod - The alias that appears in the first position after the command name will have options from the 'source-command-specific' -> 'sql-sync' record used.

@dev - The alias that appears in the second position after the command name will have options from the 'target-command-specific' -> 'sql-sync' record used.

In the typical case (`drush sql-sync @prod @dev`), the 'command-specific' record is not used at all, the 'source-command-specific' record from @prod is used, and the 'target-command-specific' record from @dev is used.

Try using alias records more like the following set:

```
/**
 * Dev/Local alias
 */
$aliases['dev'] = array(
  'root' => '/var/www/example_dev',
  'uri'  => 'example.dev',
  'path-aliases' => array(
    '%files' => 'sites/default/files',
  ),
  'target-command-specific' => array (
    'sql-sync' => array (
      'no-cache' => TRUE,
      'structure-tables-list' => 'cache,cache_admin_menu,cache_block,cache_bootstrap',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

/**
 * Live alias
 */
$aliases['live'] = array(
  'remote-host' => '000.000.00.00',
  'remote-user' => 'username',
  'root' => '/var/www/html/example-live',
  'uri'  => 'example.net',
  'path-aliases' => array(
    '%files' => 'sites/default/files',
  ),
  'source-command-specific' => array (
    'sql-sync' => array (
      'sanitize' => TRUE,
      'no-ordered-dump' => TRUE,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i dont understand all of it.

Comment: In the documentation of drush sql-sync the command is   described like this:  
`drush sql-sync @prod @dev`  
So what is?  
`drush @site sql-sync @live @dev`  

In my case live is remote and dev is the local machine, as you can see in the alias file.  

And what do you mean with:  
It is unusual for anyone to use the alias in the first position with sql-sync.

Comment: I expanded my answer for better clarity.